# Pandas pd.read_csv() splits each character into a new row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Weird (and possibly bad) question - when using the pd.read_csv() method, it appears as if pandas separates each character into a new row in the csv.

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
# doing this in colab
from google.colab import files

# downloading a csv with my apps sdk 
data = sdk.run_look('2131','csv')

with open('big.csv', 'w') as file:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    csvwriter.writerows(data)
df = pd.read_csv('big.csv', delimiter=',')
files.download('big.csv')
```

**Output:**

What I'm getting from line 4 (`data=sdk...`) looks like this:

```
Orders Status,Orders Count
complete,31377
pending,505
cancelled,375
```

However, what I get back from pandas looks like this:

```
0  r
1  d
2  e
3  r
4  s
...
```

I think it's line 6 (`df=read_csv...`) because if I do `print(data)` then compare to `print(df.head())`, I see that print data returns correct data, print df.head returns the weirdly formatted data.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here? I'm a complete noob, so probably pebkac :)

Comment: Your local big.csv file is formatted correctly?

Comment: @HenryEcker I assume - my intention is to just create a blank CSV and write to it with the  `csvwriter.writerows(data)` call. This is all being done in Google Colab so the CSV doesn't exist until I call `with open('big.csv', 'w') as file:`

Comment: Is the data you're getting just one big string?  Remember that `writerows` expects to get a list of lists.  If it is one big string, skip the `csvwriter` and do `file.write(data)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts that was it :D

Comment: thanks guys! y'all rock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your `data` is just coming in as a big string. If this is the case, you don't need to use the csv writer at all, and can just write it directly to your out file.

```py
import pandas as pd

# doing this in colab
from google.colab import files

# downloading a csv with my apps sdk 
data = sdk.run_look('2131', 'csv')

with open('big.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write(data)

df = pd.read_csv('big.csv', delimiter=',')

files.download('big.csv')
```